# How to emulate tracking to objects like the 'Nokia snake game'?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Not sure if this question has already been asked, have looked around.

I'm hoping to track objects to a specific position, in a chain or a link behind the  main object(enemy) when they have been sensed or "picked-up" by the enemy.

Something like this:
[image]

I've tried using constraints:

```
(bge.logic.nuke) = (bge.logic.nuke). constraints.new (type= 'TRACK_TO')
(bge.logic.nuke).target = context.scene.objects.get("bullseye")
```

To attempt to track the object 'nuke' to the 'bullseye' once sensed by the 'bullseye'.

However, this doesn't seem to be an attribute in the bge module.I know I've done something wrong:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'constraints'
>   Python script error - object 'Empty', controller 'Python':
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

Does anyone have any idea of any solutions?

Much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

No worries all, I found a website which describes perfectly what I wanted to do. My bad, ignore this!! Sorry.

For anyone else whom is dense, with poor research methods (like myself), please see this site:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Tracking